# Set position of ImageView based on a certain value

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I have a view in my `xml` layout with 3 blocks (each is a separate view component) of colours (RED, ORANGE, GREEN) as seen in the the following image:
[Image Of View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJZKr.png)

In the image above, there is a blue arrow which indicates the level based on a certain value :
(RED - danger, ORANGE - okay, GREEN - good)

For example,

- if the the value is `< 5` then the arrow position should be in red
- if the value is `> 10` then the arrow position should be in green
- if the value is between `6 and 9` then the arrow position should be in orange.

But I am struggling to workout how to set the  `y position` of the arrow in proportion to the layout. It does change position, but not accurately. Please assist me.

This is what I have so far in my `Activity`:

```
constraint_layout_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
               
                topHeight = greenIndicator.height 
                middleHeight = orangeIndicator.height 
                bottomHeight = redIndicator.height 

                var value = 7
               
                if(value >= 6 && value <= 9){
                     arrowIndicator.y = middleHeight - value
                 }
                
            }
        })
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you removing the listener? Did you mean to do that?

Comment: @error86 Oh sorry, no, I have updated my code.

Comment: Why don't you use 3 different arrows views for each block and then change their visibility according to the value?

Comment: If you intend to use just one arrow, then you should probably change the top and bottom constraints for arrow view rather than setting the y position